# Replicate Secondary user store configuration in WSO2 Identity Server cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have deployed WSO2 IS 5.1 cluster with 2 nodes. When I add secondary user store to one of the nodes, the configuration is stored on the filesystem of that node. The other node does not display any details related to the added secondary userstore. How do I configure such that all filesystem based configuration gets replicated across nodes in the cluster?

Do I need to use registry based depSync for this? I have tried to setup jdbc based registry for shared config and governance but I still do not see secondary userstore configuration replicating.

My registry.xml:

```
<wso2registry>
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2LocalRegistry</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="sharedregistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2RegistryDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

   <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyHandler">
       <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyMediaTypeMatcher">
           <property name="mediaType">application/xacml-policy+xml</property>
       </filter>
   </handler>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
    <id>instanceid</id>
    <dbConfig>sharedregistry</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
    <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>

<staticConfiguration>
    <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
    <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
    <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
    <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
</staticConfiguration>
</wso2registry>
```

In carbon.xml of each node:

```
<!-- Deployment Synchronizer Configuration. Uncomment the following section when running with "registry based" dep sync.
    In master nodes you need to set both AutoCommit and AutoCheckout to true
    and in  worker nodes set only AutoCheckout to true.
-->
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

Comment: Did you check whether the dep sync works? If not there can be configurations issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync files in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/` folder (`<IS_HOME>/repository/tenants/` folder if you are having multiple tenants) in a proper IS cluster.

IS have inbuilt mechanism to do that called deployment synchroniser. You can refer [1] on exact details to set that up.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Cluster/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer

Regards,

Comment: I tried to use jdbc registry based dep sync, but could not get it working

Comment: registry based dep sync is deprecated afaik. Hence its better to try with svn based dep sync or any other file sync mechanism like rsync.